# How to encode a string variable correctly to send it to Arduino via serial?

Tags: python, encoding, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-communication

I want to send value of a variable via serial from RaspberryPi to Arduino Uno.
if I type as :

```
ser.write(b'RED')
```

I can read it as RED on Arduino serial monitor. But if I type as:

```
color = "GREEN"
ser.write(color)
```

or

```
ser.write(color.encoding('utf-8'))
```

then I can't see anything. What should I do to send a string using variable?
Python and pyserial library running o Raspberry.

Comment: Did you mean `encode` instead of `endcoding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ser.write(b'RED')` is doing the same as `ser.write('RED'.encode())` so you are casting a string to its bytes equivalent then sending it to the Arduino.

`color = 'GREEN'` (what I assume you meant since `GREEN` is otherwise undefined) is not doing any conversion so you are sending a string literal with `ser.write(color)`

`ser.write(color.encode())` should do what you want